# Prevent function onkeydown javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm new to this and I have a script that will fire function on keydown. But I also have an input text field box and if I'm typing in that input field box and press the key to that fires the function. The function fires but I don't want the function to fire if I'm typing in the input field would there be a way to do this?

```js
window.addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown, true);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown() {
  var e = window.event;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 72: // Key H
      test();
      break;
  }
}

function test() {
  document.getElementById('Codefield').value = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}
```

```html
<input id="Codefield" value="" type="text">

<input id="Codefield2" value="Stop test function keydown or keydown if typeing here" type="text">
```

Comment: Do you mean [`e.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)?

Comment: Do you really have to have your function be fired out of nowhere? Isn't there an element in your UI which is supposed to receive this event and on which you could listen only when it's focused? Doing a reversed delegation is not something I would recommend... But if you really have to, you can at least check `if(document.activeElement === document.body)` to be sure no other element has the focus currently.

Answer (score 2):

If you add event listeners to `window`, all your inputs will fire the function. Add the event listener only where you need it.

```
document.getElementById('Codefield').addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown, true);
```

Another technique would be to check the `e.target` from inside the trigger function and ignore the code if it is from an input you don't want to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the current element is an input element.

```
function keyDown(e) {
  if (this.tagName == 'INPUT') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 72: // Key H
      test();
      break;
  }
}
```

Also, don't use `window.event`. That's non-standard and won't work in Firefox. The event is the first argument to the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a `focus` selector (from jQuery):

```
if($("#Codefield2:focus")) {
    thisInput = true;
}
```

Then add an `if` statement at the start of your function, and check if `thisInput` is true or not.

Comment: Which jQuery version has its toPrimitive return the id selector in this format? Really weird move from them if they really did it...

Comment: I just found it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_focus.asp) on W3Schools.

Comment: No i meant the `== "#element_id"` part. The `:focus` selector is a standard CSS selector.

Comment: Done! Happy now?

Comment: Not really ;-) `$(anything)`  is **always** truthy.